# Searching a phrase

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a big document with almost a 100 pages and at the beginning of each line is a name. I am using JavaScript in regex and the problem is that some of the names containing two words like `Alby's Mom`. 
the text that I am searching in looks like this:

```
 Alby: What is wrong?
 Alby’s Mom: Nothing child.
 Rick: Just tell him the truth!
 Alby: Yeah. I think I deserve to know!
 Little Blue Flower: (whisper) Don’t.
```

I need to choose all the names (it's just like around 10 so it's okay to just write each down) and make a list that will look like this:

```
Alby:
Alby's Mom:
Rick:
Alby:
Little Blue Flower:
```

I almost got that with

```
(\bAlby\b|\bAlby's Mom\b|\bRick\b etc.....)+
```

but the problem is that that that does not count names that have spaces in between them like Alby's Mom or Little Blue Flower.

I also don't know how to add the ":" at the end of the name because adding it to the code right after the name will result that the name like Alby that was working all along will suddenly disappear. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: How about you split each line by `:` and take the `[0]` element?

Comment: What language/tool/library are you using?

Comment: Like @RaunaqJain said, just split the array with `:` and take the first (`0th`) index. That shouldn't be hard. Update the question with the language you're using and I'll show you how,

Comment: I am using regex

Comment: "Regex" is a concept, not a programming language or tool or library.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. I am using JavaScript in regex.

Comment: Please add the code and expected result for a given sample text. It is not clear if you have all the names already and want to split the text into people and their utterances or if you need to extract just the names.

Comment: @melpomene `"Regex" is a concept` interesting definition.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this: `^\s*[^:\n]+:`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/42Jd50/3/)**

**Explained**:

```
^         # Begin of line
  \s*     # 0 or more spaces (this can be deleted if the line does not start with space)
  [^:\n]+ # Any non-':',EOL character repeated one or more times
  :       # ':' character. Remove if you don't want this
```

Comment: I tried this and it almost worked perfectly but I do not have at the beginning of each line a name and ":" after all sometimes it continues to second line and in these cases it will search everything in that line and then the name and ":" that is in the next line.

Comment: @MichalŠobr You literally said "*at the beginning of each line is a name*".

Comment: I updated the regexp to skip end of lines. If it still does not work as expected, then a complete input will be welcome

Answer (score 0):

To find the names which can be over multiple lines followed by a colon, you could `\s+` between the names to match one or more times a whitespace character.

You can use an alternation, but the reason `Alby's Mom` does not match `\bAlby's Mom\b` is because the characters `'` and `’` are different. If you want to match them both you can use a character class `['’]`

If you want to match that you could add the colon after the alternation:

[`\b(?:Alby(?:['’]s\s+Mom)?|Rick|Little\s+Blue\s+Flower):`](https://regex101.com/r/RZ9hdi/1)

```js
const regex = /\b(?:Alby(?:['’]s\s+Mom)?|Rick|Little\s+Blue\s+Flower):/g;
const str = `Alby: What is wrong?
 Alby’s Mom: Nothing child.
 Rick: Just tell him the truth!
 Alby: Yeah. I think I deserve to know!
 Little Blue Flower: (whisper) Don’t.
Alby’s
Mom:

This is a test Little
Blue Flower: test`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  console.log(m[0]);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use can use `/^.+?:/gm` either

Example [here](https://regexr.com/3u550)

Comment: For those who downvote it, could you all simple explain why? Getting downvoted without a reason is kind of unhelpful and desmotivating

Comment: Perhaps because since the `+ ` is greedy, it may not work with something such: `Alby: Bob said: Charlie is here`. (note: I did not downvote)

Comment: Use `[^:]` instead of `.`

Comment: I got it. I really appretiated your explanations. =) So, in this case, I could even use a non-greedy operator `?`. updated it!